# Working with CLSID_FilterGraph across different threads

Tags: qt, com, directshow

I'm using DirectShow in my Qt application.

To create the instance of Filter Graph, I am using QtConcurrent::run (i.e. using one of the available threads in global app thread pool).

Here's a simplified code sample that runs in QThreadPool:

```
graph_ptr createMovieGraph(const QString & file)
{
     ::CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
     auto * dst = graph_ptr(new MovieGraph(path));
     ::CoUninitialize();

     return dst;
}
```

Later, I delete my graph_ptr object in UI thread. AFAIK, QApplication UI thread works in STA threading model but deletion works without any crashes or memory leaks. Is it correct?

Sometimes I need to pause or resume my graph_ptr object in UI thread.

```
// UI Thread
_graph_ptr->pause();
```

Here's the "pause" implementatino in graph_ptr object:

```
_mediaControlInterface->Pause();
// ...
// CComPtr<IMediaControl>   _mediaControlInterface;
```

The IMediaControl interface was queried in QThreadPool at the graph_ptr object initialization time.

It turns out that I work with the object from UI thread (STA), while this object was created in QThreadPool (MTA) thread.
Everything works without crashes, but I guess I cannot use object across threads with different threading models?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ::CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
 auto * dst = graph_ptr(new MovieGraph(path));
 ::CoUninitialize();
```

This does not look well. `CoUninitialize` must be called when all COM activity is completed. To add to this, you must be checking returned status codes. On STA thread this would result in error on `CoInitializeEx` and unmatched `CoUninitialize` afterwards.

More likely than not this ends up in access violations. Maybe you just don't reach them. DirectShow uses simplified COM and you can pass raw pointers between apartments, however you have to do most important things correctly: initialization/uninitialization, reference counting. To stay out of trouble you would want to create, run, stop and release graph on STA thread.

Comment: Roman, thanks for explaining. I have one more question: does the "::CoUninitialize()" destroys MTA in my application or do not (since I have referenced the object that was created in MTA"?

Comment: `CoUninitialize` says literally: "on this thread I am done with COM". Doing COM further there might be a trouble. MTA might span over multiple threads so this call does not necessarily "destroy" MTA entirely.